# Create custom post type categories

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I've created a CPT called 'Projects' in WP using pods. If I now go to the categories sub menu for this CPT I am presented with a long list of categories that were created for the specifically for the default WP Posts.

However, I need cetegories that are limited to the Projects CPT, and not shared with any other post type. I can't seem to find any way to do this. If for example I create a new category it just gets added to the existing list of categories and is again shared with the default WP Posts.

Comment: You should create a [custom taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomies/working-with-custom-taxonomies/) (use [`register_taxonomy()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/)) and assign `projects` CPT  to it (in second parameter of `register_taxonomy()` or add to [`register_post_type()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Parameters) arguments `"taxonomies" => array('your_taxonomy_slug')` ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a NEW pod that is a Category type, then simply associate it with your CPT pod.